# Why is the event listener removed after Next.js route change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using the following `useEffect` in a component to control active state on an anchor side navigation for the page.

```
const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = (e: Event) => {
        var index = nearestIndex(
            window.scrollY,
            Anchors,
            0,
            Anchors.length - 1
        );

        setActiveIndex(index);
    }

    document.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    }
}, [Anchors]);
```

When I navigate to another page using `next/link` the `scroll` event listener is firing and then being removed. This is causing an error inside `nearestIndex` because the refs inside `Anchors` are now `null`.

EDIT: Component/Page Flow Explanation

1. Navigate to Page 1 - displays Anchor Links component with code above
2. Click anchor link - page scrolls down a bit
3. Navigate to Page 2 - does not contain Anchor Links component, `scroll` event listener fires throwing an error, listener is then removed
4. Navigate to Page 3 - does not contain Anchor Links component, no error because the `scroll` event listener is no longer registered

Answer (score 0):

Because `return` in `useEffect` works on component unmounting. Please read documentation of [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: Could you provide more of an explanation on why the unmount happens after the route has changed? Perhaps a suggestion as to what I can do differently?

Comment: I didn't work with `Next.js` but I think that it reloads web page so your components unmounted

Comment: @JasonBert Does this component exist on the new page?

Comment: @JasonBert I can advice to you to use `React Router` instead of `Next.js` router, then your page will not be reloaded. You can also try to place this component on all pages where you want his functinality

Comment: I've added an explanation of the page/component flow to the question. Ditching the Next.js router seems counter-intuitive given I'm using Next.js.

Comment: @JasonBert It was just one of option) You can also try second advice

Comment: If your page will not have this component then you will not be able to use it's `useEffect`. If it is not important for you can also remove `return` from `useEffect`

Comment: @JasonBert May be you don't need a component instead of it you need custom hook. You can read about it in [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

Comment: @JasonBert Keep in mind, whenever web page is reloading all components on it will fire their `unmounting` function

Answer (score 0):

@EzioMercer is correct. A more complete answer is that the listener is added inside of a react component, and React is mindful to clean up after itself when it destroys a component. When using the next router to navigate away from a page, this is precisely what is happening. React is tearing down the previous page's component, and cleaning up event listeners which would otherwise complain in your browser about being called after unmount if not removed.

It sounds like a simple fix for your scenario would be to return if the Anchors are null. Since you have Anchors in the dependency array, it should succeed when they become available again (when the new page is done being painted).

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (Anchors === null) return // <--- this should be all you need
    
    const handleScroll = (e: Event) => {
        var index = nearestIndex(
            window.scrollY,
            Anchors,
            0,
            Anchors.length - 1
        );

        setActiveIndex(index);
    }

    document.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    }
}, [Anchors]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fuller explanation, it's been a while since I've looked at this code but will revisit it 